# Merging add and sub functions in SafeMath.sol

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to merge the addition and subtraction function with their associated revert guard functions using OR (||) operators, but I am missing the syntax. Could anyone advise?

The functions are initially two in different blocks. I am attempting to make addition and subtraction functions into one and call them using one name in the contract. My assumption is that the OR operator could allow me do that.

I expected the new merged function to work just fine.

But I am getting the error message telling me that there is an overflow.

I want to merge the addition and subtraction function with their associated revert guard functions using OR (||) operators, but I am missing the syntax. Could anyone advise?

```
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
  bool whichOp; // to test which operator to use
  whichOp = c = a + b || c = a - b;
  whichOp = require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow") || require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
  return c;
}
```

I expected the new merged function to work just fine.

But I am getting the error message telling me that there is an overflow.

Comment: Which values are you sending to the method?

Comment: The values of 'a' and 'b'